# Координаты события мыши в D3.js, this и prototype

Tags: svg, javascript, ооп, d3.js

Пишу простой прототип, обернул основную логику в объект:

```
var Game = function(){
    this.svg = d3.select( "body").append( "svg")
        .attr( "width",  500)
        .attr( "height", 500)
    ;

    _this = this;
    this.svg.on( 'click', function(){ _this.click()});
```

Чтобы ловить клик в координатах созданного SVG определяю в прототипе ф-ю:

```
Game.prototype.click = function(){
    var M = d3.mouse( this.svg[0][0]);
    console.log( "Clicked: "+M[0]+':'+M[1]);
}
```

Вот этот "`this.svg[0][0]`" мне кажется страшным костылем, к которому я пришел методом тыка.

Как по-хорошему получить `svg` элемент DOM'а внутри коллбэка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pardon, разобрался: [`selection.node()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#node), т.е. вот так работает, и красиво:

```
var M = d3.mouse( this.svg.node() );
```